# How can I acquire more energy, other than by purchasing or waiting?

Tags: hidden-chronicles

I have been playing the game for a day now, and have noticed, the bottleneck is energy, if one wants to keep playing..

Now, energy accumulates over time all-right, and it can also be purchased online, but, I wonder, is there any other way of filling up your energy bar and keeping it that way?

Comment: I've never played the game, but I would say probably not - the point is to get you to spend money.

Comment: That's why people use the scare quotes around "Free" facebook games.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the experience bar fills up and you gain a level, you gain also extra energy, AND your maximum energy increases too.

Also, keep a high number of friends (neighbors). You can share/gift energy with your friends, where chances are high you will gain more energy too.

Visit your neighbors every day. This will net you extra energy.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on whatever game you're playing, you can "level up" by gaining experience or whatever the case may be, and by doing so it will replenish your energy for further use. That's pretty much all I can gather, though. Hope this helps, even in the slightest!